# Creating a column as XML content

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to understand the concept behind creating a column as XML schema

```
CREATE TABLE RACK
([grid_Lines] [xml](CONTENT [dbo].[gridLinesSchema]) NULL)
```

What exactly is being stored and I was not able to find anywhere the gridLinesSchema..?? Where can I find a good walk-thru of this XML concept ?

Comment: [CONTENT Specifies that each instance of the xml data type in column_name can comprise multiple top-level elements. CONTENT applies only to the xml data type and can be specified only if xml_schema_collection is also specified. If this is not specified, CONTENT is the default behavior.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-table-column-definition-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: You can also look at the datatype definition. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/xml/xml-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: So, do I have to create the XML schema called gridLinesSchema first and then associate a database column...I am not able to get it to work